# New field created is not being displayed in the backend order

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, backend, custom-field

I created a new field for the client to fill the same in the checkout. I created it from the following code in an sql file:

```
<?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->addAttribute("customer", "referencia",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Referencia",
        "input"    => "text",
        "source"   => "",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => false,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => "")
    );

    $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "referencia");

    $used_in_forms=array();

    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
    $used_in_forms[] = "customer_address_edit";
    $used_in_forms[] = "customer_address";
            $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100)
            ;
            $attribute->save();

    $installer->endSetup();
?>
```

In the billing.phtml file, I added the following `input`:

```
<div class="field referencia">
    <div class="field small small-left left">
       <label for="billing:referencia"><?php echo $this->__('Referência: ') ?></label>
       <div class="input-box">
            <input style="width: 100% !important;" class="input-text" id="billing:referencia" name="billing[referencia]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Pontos de Referência') ?>" onchange="salvarDadosSession(5,$j(this).val())" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPontoReferencia(); ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

If I enter a client in the backend and go into account information, the "referencia" field appears there normally, but when a purchase is completed and goes in the same order in the backend, it does not appear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reread what you did, you say that you added the attribute in the **db** and in the **front** good, and **backend ?** if you don't add it in the backend too, it's not going to add himself alone, So you have to extend the `grid` or the `order informations` (it depends on where you want to display it) and you add it.

Here is an exemple via an observer how to add your custom attribute in **Sales order grid** :

**app/etc/modules/My_Module.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </module>
        </models>
    </global>

    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <!-- To register the controller action -->
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml>
                <observers>
                    <my_module_custom_register>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>registerController</method>
                    </my_module_custom_register>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml>
            <!-- Called after creating a block -->
            <core_layout_block_create_after>
                <observers>
                    <my_module_custom_before_block>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>blockCreateAfter</method>
                    </my_module_custom_before_block>
                </observers>
            </core_layout_block_create_after>
            <!-- Called before loading a non EAV collection -->
            <core_collection_abstract_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <my_module_custom_before_core_load_collection>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeCoreCollectionLoad</method>
                    </factoryx_custom_before_core_load_collection>
                </observers>
            </core_collection_abstract_load_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Observer.php:**

```
<?php

class My_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function registerController(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName();
        switch ($action)
        {
            case 'adminhtml_sales_order_index':
            case 'adminhtml_sales_order_grid':
            case 'adminhtml_sales_order_exportCsv':
            case 'adminhtml_sales_order_exportExcel':
                Mage::register('adminhtml_sales_order_grid', true);
                break;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function blockCreateAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();

        if($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid)
        {
            $block->addColumnAfter(
                'referencia',
                array(
                    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Account Reference'),
                    'index' => 'referencia',
                    'filter_index' => 'cust.value',
                ),
                'created_at'
            );
        }
    }

    public function beforeCoreCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

        if (Mage::registry('adminhtml_sales_order_grid')) {

            $collection = $observer->getCollection();
            if (!isset($collection)) {
                return;
            }

            if ($collection instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection) {
                // Get the attribute id for the referencia attribute
                $eavAttribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
                $referenciaId = $eavAttribute->getIdByCode('customer', 'referencia');
                $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    array('cust' => Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getTableName('customer_entity_varchar')),
                    'main_table.customer_id = cust.entity_id AND cust.attribute_id = '.$referenciaId,
                    array(
                        'cust.value'
                    )
                );
}
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/99000/48355)